# Multiple UV mapping in 2.8 eevee?

Tags: uv

How do you texture map with multiple UV's in 2.8? I need at least 2 sets of UV's for the way im texturing but I can't figure out how to do it in the new blender

All the videos if doing this are from years ago and the UI of whats happening on screen doesn't match mine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add UV maps using the '+' button in the ObjectData tab (on right on the image).

Then use it in the node editor, from the 'input' category (on left on the image).

[image]

Then you can use them in the node tree as you want.

[image]

How to switch UV maps in the UV Editor window:

[image]